# How to interpolate a string in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a bunch of strings stored in a config file. The strings contain values that must be evaluated at runtime:

```
"aaa #{val1} bbb"
"ccc #{val235} ddd"
```

How can I replace the `#{valN}` at runtime using the standard, out of the box, Haskell library? Do **string interpolations**, that is.

I can change the **format** of parts that have to be interpolated, if Haskell requires so. Namely, instead of `#{valN}` I could use `${valN}` or anything else.

Comment: Why can’t `printF` work? After all, `… -> String` is an instance of `PrintF`.

Comment: @bradrn where do you get that?

Comment: `PrintfType t` is not a type, but a type constraint. It is satisfied by `String`, so you can use you use `printf .... :: String` to choose `t = String`. I'm not sure about how `printf` helps in your task, though.

Comment: @chi ok, but how about Text?

Comment: I meant, where did you get that `String is an instance of PrintF`?

Comment: @Jorshurau Unfortunately, `Text` isn’t supported. As for `String` being a `PrintF` instance, it’s right at the bottom: `instance IsChar c => PrinfType [c]`, `instance IsChar Char`. **EDIT:** You can click on `PrintfType` to get to a description including a list of instances, which is how I found it.

Comment: Can you define "standard, out of the box Haskell library"?

Comment: Not quite sure why you have this "out of the box" library constraint. Why can't you use other libraries? Haskell with the Standard Prelude doesn't have this capability built in, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Well, ok, I will proceed without your input then. If your definition is "only `base` and nothing else", then I'm afraid you're your're out of luck, because the type `Text` comes from [the `text` package](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.3/text-1.2.4.0/Data-Text.html#t:Text), different from `base`. So you need to either drop the `Text` requirement (in which case `printf` works), or you need to redefine what "out of the box means". If this term includes the `text` package, then the next question is, what's the difference between the `text` package and other packages?

Comment: Voting to close. Not only is the question unclear, but the OP is responding with abuse.

Comment: Perhaps this insistence on "out of the box" is a misguided attempt to avoid running afoul of SO's rules against asking for library recommendations and off-site resources. If so, I have bad news: what you're asking is such a request anyway. Voting to close.

Comment: @DanielWagner previous questions from the OP had a similar "out of the box" requirement. This makes me more inclined to think that behind this requirement there is either a deeper truth or a misunderstanding of the Haskell ecosystem.

Comment: I guess what OP means by "out of the box" is probably using the core libraries provided with GHC.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there are three ways to do what you want:

### 1. `(++)` operator

Since `String` is just a list of `Char`, so you can use `(++)` operator to combine many strings:

```hs
> "aaa " ++ show (val1) ++ " bbb"
> "ccc " ++ show (val235) ++ " ddd"
```

### 2. `printf`

`printf` can really return `String` type:

```hs
λ> printf "Hi, %s!" "Bob" :: String
"Hi, Bob!"
λ> :t it
it :: String
```

So all you need to do is giving a explicit type signature to your function which you need to return `String`.

### 3. [string-interpolate package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/string-interpolate)

The following is the sample code from the package [document](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/string-interpolate-0.2.0.0/docs/Data-String-Interpolate.html)

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}

import Data.Text
import Data.String.Interpolate ( i )

λ> age = 33 :: Int
λ> name = "Tatiana" :: Text
λ> [i|{"name": "#{name}", "age": #{age}}|] :: String
>>> "{\"name\": \"Tatiana\", \"age\": 33}"

λ> [i|
Name: #{name}
Age: #{age}
|] :: String
>>> "\nName: Tatiana\nAge: 33\n"
```

Of course, there are some other interpolation libraries, which are also listed in the package pages.

Comment: 1) a string comes from a config file, it can't contain Haskell code! 2) I'm aware of that -- now I need Text rather than String 3) using the *standard Haskell* library - out of the box!

Comment: Well, since you need `Text`, so you can't avoid the *text* package. Then, you can still use `printf` with the helpers of `pack` and `unpack`.

Comment: `the helpers of pack and unpack` -> how?

Comment: @Jorshurau `pack :: String -> Text` and `unpack :: Text -> String` maybe help, and you can write something like `pack $ printf "Hi %s, my age is %d." "Bob" 30`.

Answer (score 1):

An option not mentioned in the comments or in Z-Y.L's answer is [`typelits-printf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/typelits-printf):

```hs
ghci> putStrLn $ printf @"You have %.2f dollars, %s" 3.62 "Luigi"
You have 3.62 dollars, Luigi
```

See more examples on https://github.com/mstksg/typelits-printf